# How to post data and respone XMLparser set to UITableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I receive some data in XML format from a php server. I use XMLParser to parse the response. I am able to parse the data and confirmed it by NSLoging the parsed data. My issue is that I am not able to load the parsed data to the UITableView.

```
    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{



        if([elementName isEqualToString: subject]){
            [dict setObject: currentSubject forKey: subject];
        }else if([elementName isEqualToString: newsid]){
            [dict setObject: currentID forKey: newsid];


            // Add Object
        }else if([elementName isEqualToString: @"user"]){
            [myObject addObject: dict];    
        }
        [mytable reloadData];
    }

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

    NSLog(@"Gallery list array has %d items", [myObject count]);
    NSMutableDictionary *data;
    for(int i = 0; i < [myObject count]; i ++){
        data = [myObject objectAtIndex: i];
        NSLog(@"\nGalleryID: %@\nName: %@\n\n",
              [data objectForKey: subject],
              [data objectForKey: newsid]);
            }

    // Reload Data
    [mytable reloadData];
}


// delegate for TableView

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return myObject.count;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        // Use the default cell style.
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle : UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle
                                       reuseIdentifier : CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    NSDictionary *tmpDict = [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [tmpDict objectForKey:subject];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: what you tried paste your code

Answer (score 1):

If you used XML Parser delegate methods,write [myTable reloadData] in did end element method.Its working for me smoothly.Please try this.

Comment: @PranotS.Johnnie...what do u mean by "some time it won't work"?...traced the issue?

Comment: I back to before view and click button to Parser view again. data not show. but Log have data.

Answer (score 0):

Implement **[NSXMLParser](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/NSXMLParserDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008632-CH1-SW4)**'s delegate method called,

```
- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser
{
//reload your tableview...
}
```

Sent by the parser object to the delegate when it has successfully completed parsing.

Comment: why ur reloading ur tableview twice...in didEndElement and didEndDocument [mytable reloadData]; @PranotS.Johnnie

Comment: try to log [myObject objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] in cellForRowAtIndexPath method...when u go back to this view again...